# Is there something similar to android:stateNotNeeded for wp app

Tags: android, silverlight, windows-phone-7, state

Is there something similar to `android:stateNotNeeded`  for Windows-phone-7 app(XAML)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Phone abides to a different set of state saving rules compared to Android. Read up on [tombstoning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh148153.aspx). The SDK itself does not offer a flag that lets you ignore the current state because in most cases it is the developer's job to organize the state storage.